# C#/MVC can I manually append multiple Enum Flags in a foreach loop?

Tags: model-view-controller, enums, flags

I've seen ways of using HTML Helpers and such to deal with enums in MVC. I've taken a different approach in that I pass a string[] of the checked boxes back to the controller. I am doing this:

```
            foreach (string svf in property.SiteVisibilityFlags)
            {                                     
                Enums.SiteVisibilityFlags flagTester;
                if (Enum.TryParse<Enums.SiteVisibilityFlags>(svf, out flagTester))
                {
                    // add to domainProperty
                    domainProperty.SiteVisibilityFlags = flagTester; <--Here is where I mean
                }
            }
```

Now, I know that normally, with a flagged enum you do something like:

```
     domainProperty.SiteVisibilityFlags = Enums.SiteVisibilityFlags.Corporate | Enums.SiteVisibilityFlags.Properties;
```

So, if/how can I accomplish the '|'... in this methodology?

Comment: you are trying to cast the strings back to enum ... so what's the problem.. could you clarify a bit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. Any enum that has [Flags] as an attribute can be solved by summing up the values of all checked items like this:

```
// Site Visibility Flags        
            int SiteVisibilityTotalValue = 0;
            foreach (string svf in property.SiteVisibilityFlags)
            {
                Enums.SiteVisibilityFlags flagTester;
                if (Enum.TryParse<Enums.SiteVisibilityFlags>(svf, out flagTester))
                {
                    // sum up values to get total to them convert to enum
                    SiteVisibilityTotalValue += (int)flagTester;
                }
            }
            // convert total to Enum
            domainProperty.SiteVisibilityFlags = (Enums.SiteVisibilityFlags)SiteVisibilityTotalValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `[FlagAttribute]` explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
From there you can simply use the `bit-or (|) operator` as follows

```
domainProperty.SiteVisibilityFlags |= flagTester;
```

Also there is a really good explanation with examples [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c) about attribute

Comment: yes, as I mentioned I am using the flags attribute, but your answer didn't solve the problem. thanks anyway.